# Set $_SESSION global variable before running PHP from the command line

Tags: php, command-line

I try to output my .php files from the command line and I want to be able to simulate `$_SESSION` values for this output.

I tried `php test.php --define $_SESSION["id"]=1` but it does not set the global variable `$_SESSION`.

I am obviously not using the command line correctly but I cannot find how I should do.

Any idea to make it work?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: for my example test.php is the following:

```
<? echo $_SESSION['id'];?>
```

Comment: So you're not doing a `session_start()` anywhere in the php file?

Comment: Nope, I figured it would over ride a preset value of `$_SESSION` and wondered if I could use this global variable as a regular variable. I will try with it.

Comment: After testing, if I do `session_start()`, the `$_SESSION` variable is set to `array()`, which is not the cas if I do not do it (I checked with `print_r`. Everything looks like my --define does not do anything (or at least not what I expect)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I serve a different page if the user is logged in and if he is not (which I know from the `$_SESSION` variable). Now I am trying to output a static version of my connected page to build a native app with phone gap, that does not know PHP. I want to write a script that exports the logged in version of the page to a standard HTML I use in my phonegap app. Does it make sense? Any easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat setsession.php 
<?php
//fixed session:
session_id("fixed");
session_start();
?>
$ cat checksession.php 
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;

$_SESSION['counter']++;

var_dump($_SESSION);
$ php -d auto_prepend_file=setsession.php checksession.php 
array(1) {
  ["counter"]=>
  int(1)
}
$ php -d auto_prepend_file=setsession.php checksession.php 
array(1) {
  ["counter"]=>
  int(2)
}
$ php -d auto_prepend_file=setsession.php checksession.php 
array(1) {
  ["counter"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works just like magic. It definitely makes more sense that all the shaky workarounds I tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use sessions on the command line in any meaningful way – the session identifier gets stored in a cookie. The command line doesn't do cookies, so the normal way of sessions doesn't work. Of course, you can use the `$_SESSION` superglobal during the run of the script. Just don't expect it to persist between different calls of the same script.

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes perfect sense but I did not expect any persistence. I just wanted to preset the `$_SESSION` variable (as any variable) before running the script. I tried `-B` and `-d` options but with no luck.

Comment: Ah, then I think I begin to understand. `-d` defines ini keys, not variables. `php test.php -B '$_SESSION["abc"]="test";' ` might achieve what you want to be doing.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood `-d` however `-B '$_SESSION["abc"]="test";'` does not seem to be properly setting the variable, neither does `-B '$_SESSION=array("abc"=>"test");'`, not sure why :-/

Comment: The `-B` would work equally well as the prepend file I proposed, but (1) we need a session-ident, (2) a `session_start` destroys a previously set `$_SESSION`, so, it would be `-B 'session_id("fixedorsomething");session_start();$_SESSION["abc"]="test";'`. I just prefer to put that stuff in a file so my command line isn't so cluttered (and I don't have to remember every setup, just use the same file next time).